# glDrawElementsInstanced fps drop on first primitive

Tags: opengl, 3d

I'm trying to render multiple cubes along the x and z axis. Since there are a lot of cubes and they only the position differs, I thought I would use glDrawElementsInstanced. And it's working great, but I have an fps drop when the Engine is rendering the first cube (at the origin).
I'm thinking it's drawing multiple cube on top of each other which could cause drawing the same triangles multiple times at the same position, and I tried to not render the first block by using `gl_InstanceID == 0` but it's drawing it anyway.

Here are the illustrations of my problem :
Here I have 21 FPS : when i'm near the first cube.

[image]

And here, I have 60 fps since i'm far (I get 60 fps when i'm like 5 cubes far from the original):

[image]

And here is my vertex shader :

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position; 
layout (location = 1) in vec3 offset; 

void main(void){
    vec4 pos = u_transform * vec4(position, 1); 
    pos += vec4(offset.x, 0, offset.z, 0); 
    gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * u_viewMatrix * pos;  
}
```

I'm drawing the cube normally with indices, I can put the code here if you want.
Thank you.

**I have the solution, I'll post it later**

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself it seems he is rendering the cubes multiple times. Means that it's likly that you have something wrong in your setup of the instancing data.

Try to render fewer cubes or try to skip instances ( see link below ) to lock down the issue. You could also try to enter some instancing data manually to see what causes the issue.

Rendering instances with some instances skipped: [glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertexBaseInstance](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertexBaseInstance.xml)

Comment: I used glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertexBaseInstance and skipped the the first one, nothing changed. Then I tried to skip the first five primitives and it skipped the four primitives after the first one. Skipping the indices changed nothing. I really think it's drawing the cube at the origin for each instance. Maybe something wron with my code, I edit my post to include it, could you take a look ? thank you by the way !

Comment: @R00t Yes but my guess it that the offset data of some vertices might be wrong.